# How to make an action after a button click?

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I've been looking all over the forum for answers but no matter how many times I modify it, there's always an error that comes up. it says "Main activity must be abstract or implement abstract method onClick(View) in onClickListener" Here is my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
{
  /*
   *Everything here is Array Strings and other variables that are unrelated to the problem.
   * I chose not to post them because they would have tooken to much unnecessary space
   */
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    button1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    button2 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    button3 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button3));
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);

         OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    //DO something
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    //DO something
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    //DO something
                    break;
            }
        }

};
}
```

Comment: [What is an Interface?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the onClickListener to this, then you shouldn't be creating a new OnClickListener, the onClick function should be on the activity class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a new OnClickListener in your activity, because your activity is already an OnclickListener as you have implemented the interface (but not completely with the methods). Just implement the methods of the Listener.
It is one of two possibilities: Implement the interface in your activity or create an anonymous listener. You have done both.

Answer (score 0):

"Main activity must be abstract or implement abstract method onClick(View) in onClickListener" means your class is missing the implementation of the method onClick().

Read What is an interface ?: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

2 solutions to make it work:

**First solution**:
You remove

```
implements OnClickListener
```

and you define set to you buttons the listener you defined on the onCreate method:

```
OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                //DO something
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                //DO something
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                //DO something
                break;
        }
    }

button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
button3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Second solution:

You implement the onClick() method in the class itself:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    button1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    button2 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    button3 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button3));
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            //DO something
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            //DO something
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            //DO something
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

When I search for the views by their id's, i find them. But when I use the variables that store the textviews, they can't be recognized and i'm constantly told that they are no where to be found. My button don't give me probles. Only the textviews keeps saying "Cannot resolve symbol"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    button1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    button2 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    button3 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button3));
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    TextView textview1, textview2, textview3, questionView, questionView2, questionNumber;

    textview1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1));
    textview2 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2));
    textview3 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3));
    questionView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView));
    questionView2 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView2));
    questionNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumber);
}

   @Override

        public void onClick( View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:



                    if(questionIndex < questions.length -1
                            )

                        if (questionIndex != 5){
                            textview2.setText("");
                        } if (questionIndex == 5){
                    textview2.setText(halfQues8);
                }
```

// make sure the index is in bounds

```
                    questionIndex++ ; // increment the index


                    questionValue ++;



                    questionView.setText(Questions[questionIndex]); // set the text to the next question

    /*
     * set the text to the next answer options
     */
                    textview1.setText(answerButtA[questionIndex]);
                    textview2.setText(answerButtB[questionIndex]);
                    textview3.setText(answerButtC[questionIndex]);
                    questionNumber.setText("Question " + questionValueS + ".");

            }

            else{

                questionView.setText("Complete");
                questionNumber.setText("");
                questionView2.setText("");

                textview1.setText("");
                textview2.setText("");
                textview3.setText("");
                Results.setText("Click here for results");
            }






            break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    //DO something
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    //DO something
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: this is clearly NAA, as evidenced by the fact that the poster has **created another question** about this